# How can I define a ResourceDictionary to a ContentPresenter within my custom control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

**tl;dr:** I want the consumer of my custom control to be able to define which separate resources two inner ContentPresenters of the custom control are to use. Side note: the ContentPresenters themselves will be part of DataTemplates, i.e. not explicit members of the custom control.

I'm creating a custom control that will use two `ContentPresenter` instances. The `ContentTemplate` used by each of these instances should be determined by defining DataTemplates using `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type someType}">`, i.e. the presenters will find the right template based on the data type.

As I understand, a `ContentPresenter` will search through static resources, starting with its' own, then traversing up the logical tree and, finally, checking for application-level resources.

Developers using the custom control should be able to specify a `ResourceDictionary` for each of the two `ContentPresenter` instances.

Just to illustrate my intention: if I were wanting to customize two `DataTemplate`s for each of the presenters, I could so something like this:

**CustomControl.xaml.cs snippet**:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(HeaderTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DynamicDataGridControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate)));

public DataTemplate HeaderTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(HeaderTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(HeaderTemplateProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CellTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(CellTemplate), typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DynamicDataGridControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(DataTemplate)));

public DataTemplate CellTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(CellTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CellTemplateProperty, value); }
}
```

**CustomControl.xaml snippet**

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderPresenter" ContentTemplate="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=HeaderTemplate}"/>
...
<ContentPresenter x:Name="CellPresenter" ContentTemplate="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=CellTemplate}"/>
```

And the others could use the custom control like this:

**ConsumingControl.xaml snippet**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyHeaderTemplate">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
    
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyCellTemplate">
        ...
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<CustomControl HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyHeaderTemplate}" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyCellTemplate}"/>
```

Now I would like to do basically the same, but instead of explicitly defining the `ContentTemplate`, I would like to define the `ResourceDictionary` or scope for each control.

I tried adding a `DependencyProperty` of type `ResourceDictionary` to my custom control and then referencing it as shown below, but it only leads to an exception: A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'ResourceDictionary'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

```
<ContentPresenter>
    <ContentPresenter.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=CellResources}"></ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPresenter.Resources>
</ContentPresenter>
```

The reason for this is, that the types may be the same for both content presenters, but they should be rendered differently. I could achieve what I need (more or less) by specifying a converter, but I would much prefer to do it as outlined above. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance once again!

Comment: Even with all the information I am very confused by what you're trying to accomplish with the ResourceDictionary. Is it possible to give more information or clarify how you want to use the ResourceDictionary?

Comment: Why is it a custom control? I can't see anything that adds other than complication over a usercontrol. Why not just say a headered contentcontrol and datatemplates?   Why not load the resource dictionary at entry point and use datatype to choose template based on viewmodel type? Why is the answer the same viewmodel type for header and child?